# How to change default Window Manager for XRDP

Tags: debian, remote-access, window-managers, xrdp

I don't know if this question makes any sense, but here it's the problem:

I have a virtual Debian machine that I only use terminal. Most of the time, I'm using it via ssh.

I installed gparted to manage some disk, so I had to install xorg, lightdm and fluxbox. It was working great with rdp from Windows. I then decided to install cinnamon, but found it too heavy for my virtual machine. I uninstaled cinnamon, but now when I try to connect it, it says that cinnamon was not found. How do I set fluxbox as default?

Comment: Do you see a graphic login screen, before going to WM?

Comment: Let's put aside the remote connection. When I load up the machine, it fails to start the xsession, so I'm stuck with terminal mode only. If I type in `startx`, it trys to load graphical mode but fails with an error message: "Failed to load session Cinnamon". I don't have Cinnamon installed anymore, only Fluxbox.

Comment: If you only whan to use gparted, why don't you use the terminal version : parted ?

Answer (score 1):

The simple case, which is not your case, it is to use a display manager: it is the program which handles the graphical logic, and it starts the windows manager/desktop environment (and it is configurable).

Because you do not have a WM, you should use the old way: you can change the default VM:

```
update-alternatives --config x-window-manager
```

or you reinstall the windows manager (so it can set itself as default), or just reconfiguring it (`dpkg-reconfigure -plow fluxbox`)

You may want also to change your `.xinitrc`, e.g. like in https://wiki.debian.org/FluxBox#From_Commandline.

As very last option: you may check also https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-reference/ch07.en.html#_starting_the_x_window_system, to check the numerous files that are read at start of X, which could be modified by `cinnamon` (the user configuration side) or yourself.  Starting x from console seems no more fashionable, so bugs can happen (and they can live undiscovered).